# Backbone JS parse json attribute to a collection's model

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js, collections

I'm having trouble parsing a json to a model.

Here is the JSON:

```
[
{
    "name": "Douglas Crockford",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "_id": "50f5f5d4014e045f000002",
    "__v": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "cena1": "Cena1",
            "cena2": "Cena2",
            "cena3": Cena3,
            "cena4": "Cena4",
            "cena5": "Cena5",
            "cena6": Cena6,
            "_id": "50ee3e782a3d30fe020001"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

And i need a model to have the 'items' attributes like this:

```
cena = new Model({ 
           cena1: "Cena1", 
           cena2: "Cena2",
           ... 
});
```

What I've tried:

```
var cenaCollection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Cenas,
   url: '/orders',

   parse: function (response) {
      return this.model = response.items;
   }

});
```

then I create new instance of the collection and fetch, but i get "response.items" always "undefined" :|

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `parse` function should return the attributes hash to be set on the model (see the [documentation here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse)).  So you'll need simply:

```
parse: function (response) {
   return response[0].items;
}
```

Comment: @asirgado I just noticed your JSON seems to be wrapped in an array -- is that correct?  If so you'll need instead `response[0].items` ...?

Comment: just tried that and it works as I need! Thanks!! If I get more 'items' inside the array will it work? Thanks!